# typeOrm unique row

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to make a Entity using typeOrm on my NestJS, and it's not working as I expected.

I have the following entity

```js
@Entity('TableOne')
export class TableOneModel {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @PrimaryColumn()
  tableTwoID: number

  @PrimaryColumn()
  tableThreeID: number

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt?: Date
}
```

This code generate a migration that generates a table like the example below

```
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+----------------------+-------+
| Field        | Type        | Null | Key | Default              | Extra |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+----------------------+-------+
| id           | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL                 |       |
| tableTwoID   | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL                 |       |
| tableThreeID | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL                 |       |
| createdAt    | datetime(6) | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) |       |
+--------------+-------------+------+-----+----------------------+-------+
```

That's ok, the problem is, that I want to the table only allow one row with `tableTwoID` and `tableThreeID`, what should I use in the Entity to generated the table as I expected it to be?

Expected to not allow rows like the example below

```
+----+------------+--------------+----------------------------+
| id | tableTwoID | tableThreeID | createdAt                  |
+----+------------+--------------+----------------------------+
|  1 |          1 |            1 | 2019-10-30 19:27:43.054844 |
|  2 |          1 |            1 | 2019-10-30 19:27:43.819174 |    <- should not allow the insert of this row
+----+------------+--------------+----------------------------+
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try marking the column as Unique

@Unique()
ColumnName

Comment: Thanks, this tip helped to solve my problem, I've used this like this `@Unique('uniqueTableTwoIDTableThreeID', ['tableTwoID', 'tableThreeID'])`

Comment: Annotating the entity class not the column will yield a composite key

Answer (score 4):

This is currently expected behavior from TypeORM. According to the documentation if you have multiple `@PrimaryColumn()` decorators you create a composite key. The combination of the composite key columns must be unique (in your above `'1' + '1' + '1' = '111'` vs `'2' + '1' + '1' = '211'`). If you are looking to make each column unique along with being a composite primary key, you should be able to do something like `@PrimaryColumn({ unique: true })`

Comment: I got the message "Error: Sqlite does not support AUTOINCREMENT on composite primary key" when using multiple `@PrimaryColumn()` decorators with TypeORM and "sqlite3".